# ClassCastException+spring

Tags: tomcat6

Hi                                                                                         following error I have got please let me know solution

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor cannot be cast to org.apache.AnnotationProcessor –

Im using tomcat 6.0

Comment: Could you provide more details as to how you are getting this exception?

Comment: got the clue installed tomcat server 7.0 and it started working might be issue with tomcat 6.0

Comment: Found the reason and the solution. Added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. This is the reason:

> This was due to efforts from MYFACES-1246, proposal of annotation 
>   processing here in list (adding method), but this of course breaks 
>   compatibility of the same named interfaces.

If you have older code using org.apache.AnnotationProcessor you can make 
it work on Tomcat.

Solution is:

Add `<Loader delegate="true"/>` into context.xml file (to Context element) in tomcat/conf directory.

This makes classloading in Tomcat sticking to J2EE spec.
(I couldn't make it work with suggested approach for only 1 webapp)

This is the reference: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-dev/200703.mbox/%3C45F6D22B.1020803@ataco.cz%3E